# R: help needed to write same code using apply function in R

Tags: r

i need to repeat same row of data frame for n number of times and row bind them to new data frame.

I can easily do it using for loop, but it has more computational time. Can some one help me this doing using any of apply functions.

Below one is the prototype of my code.

```
testdata<-data.table(v1=sample(1000),v2=sample(1000),v3=sample(1000),v4=as.integer(runif(1000,1,10)))## Sample data
testdata1<-data.table(v1=NA,v2=NA,v3=NA,v4=NA)##creating empty data frame
for(i in 1:nrow(testdata)){
  temp<-testdata[i,][rep(seq_len(nrow(testdata[i,])), each=testdata$v4[i]),]
  testdata1<-rbind(temp,testdata1)
}
```

Comment: `nrow(testdata[i,])` ... this does not make sense to me.  It will always return `1`, no?

Comment: yes, as i am looping over each row it will return only 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need a loop to do this as `rep` is vectorized.

```
testdata[rep(seq_len(.N),  testdata$v4)]
```

In the above code, `.N` represents the row count and by wrapping with `seq_len`, we get the sequence.  i.e. if the number of rows is 1000, it will give `1:1000`

Just to demonstrate with a small example

```
rep(1:3, c(3,4,6))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

Comment: Can you please explain what .N does here? does it take each row at a time? As far as i know .N is used to get the count.

Comment: Yes, It worked. Thanks for the solution . Ticked as correct